# C++ garbage collection and circularly referenced data

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, circular-reference

I'm currently implementing my garbage collector (in C++) using reference counting technique. However, there's a major problem is that if the data is circularly referenced, they're never collected since their reference counts are always non-zero.

I tried searching around and found these things called tracing garbage collector, mark-and-sweep algorithm, etc. Is it possible for me to implement one? And how exactly do they work?

Comment: Look into weak references. Also, try to avoid circular references altogether.

Comment: This isn't a very well formed question.  Of course you can implement one, and you should look into a good programming languages book to understand how those garbage collection algorithms work.

Comment: Agreed with CPP: If you think about it, there can never be a truly symmetric circular reference. Someone always has to come first. So the final edge in the "circle" should be a "weak reference", which solves the problem.

Comment: @Michael Price: Most resources I've found so far just go on and on explaining about various terms, and none of them actually bothered to give some examples. I really don't care how the OS, or the compiler, or the Java language collect the garbage, I care about how I can do it myself. And so far, no luck. Reference counting does not accurately collect all the garbage, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Cat: "Also, try to avoid circular references altogether": It's not the business of a garbage collector to impose restrictions on the programmer!

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to implement it but im not sure if you really want to :)

Comment: @TonyK: while it may not be desirable, ALL garbage collectors place restrictions on the programmer, so when writing a program using a garbage collector you need to be aware of its foibles and restrictions.

Comment: @Chris: Then Cat Plus Plus should have said: "Also, inform your users that they should try to avoid circular references altogether." Which means something completely different.

Comment: @TonyK: Eh? That reference counting cannot deal with circular references very well is a well-known limitation. I was talking about the application developer that introduces circular references in their code.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: There are many problems that require circular references between objects.  Imposing that restriction because of an implementation detail (garbage collection can be implemented otherwise) is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic problem in garbage collector design.  Take a look at the [Garbage Collection article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), it's really good in presenting the different trade-offs in garbage collector design.  The "more evolved" algorithms like tri-color marking are actually quite simple and easy to implement.  I've used that those instructions to implement a tracing collector for my own Lisp implementation in C.

The most complex thing to handle in tracing garbage collectors is walking object trees (e.g. finding references to "live" objects).  If you are writing an interpreter for another language, this is not too hard because you can wire in facilities for this in your root object class (or other common denominator to all objects).  However, if you're writing a garbage collector for C++ in C++, then you'll have a hard time doing this because you need to inspect object contents to find pointers to other allocated regions of memory.

If you are writing a garbage collector for educational purposes, I recommend that you look into writing an interpreter for another language (one that does not have direct access to pointers).  If you're writing a collector for C++ in C++ with the intent of using it in production software, I strongly recommend that you use [an existing production-quality implementation](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/) instead.

Comment: The link is dead, update it please.

Comment: @Javid Link updated!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm

> "The weak_ptr class template stores a "weak reference" to an object
>   that's already managed by a shared_ptr. To access the object, a
>   weak_ptr can be converted to a shared_ptr using the shared_ptr
>   constructor or the member function lock. When the last shared_ptr to
>   the object goes away and the object is deleted, the attempt to obtain
>   a shared_ptr from the weak_ptr instances that refer to the deleted
>   object will fail: the constructor will throw an exception of type
>   boost::bad_weak_ptr, and weak_ptr::lock will return an empty
>   shared_ptr."

You shouldn't have circular references really, but if you're working with a design where you can't refactor them out (which does happen occasionally), try placing weak pointers in one of the directions so they don't prevent the destruction.

Comment: This is good advice if you're managing resources without a garbage collector, but doesn't help the OP to implement a garbage collector.

Comment: +1 - This answer is useful as an easy way to solve the problem behind the literal question.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to solve the problem I'm having with my current GC. Because if the user uses it to control something like a circularly linked list, then it fails.

Comment: -1 To offset the +1: this is rarely a workable solution, and cycles are implicit in many data structures (graphs, etc.).

Comment: @user1065635 - Are (or your team) the user, or do you have external users?